# CSS selector on TD contents

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table whose TD's contain ordinary text.  Is there a way to style (e.g. set the background color) on a TD according to the TD's contents?  For example, I might want GO to have a green background, while RED should have a red background.

I've tried these without success:

```
td[innerText='GO']
td[innerHtml='GO']
td[outerText='GO']
```

Of course I could set a class or an explicit style for each TD according to its contents, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use javascript to check the contents, and then alter the style of your `td` tag.

You may have a function in a `script.js` file:

```
function tdStyle(current_table) {

    var tds = current_table.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

        if (tds[i].textContent == "string1" || tds[i].innerText == "string1") {
            tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (td_tag.textContent == "string2" || tds[i].innerHTML == "string2") {
            tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else if (td_tag.textContent == "string3" || tds[i].innerHTML == "string3") {
            tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }

    }

}
```

And then you use this function in your `table` tag, like:

```
<table onload="tdStyle(this);">
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

Notice the comparison is made with both `tds[i].textContent` and `tds[i].innerText`, as the later is required for IE.